# Using sed command with delimiter character

Tags: regex, sed

I have a text file as below containing multiple lines with `=` in the middle of each line.

```
User name      =  user1
Date expire    =  Oct 20, 2019
```

I want to find `Date expire` and replace the right side of `=` which is the date with something else via `sed`. For example, `Oct 25, 2019`.

I know basic usage of `sed 's/foo/bar/g'` but that is used for fixed strings. I want to change part of the sentence by detecting a special character.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
sed '/Date expire/s/\(.*= \).*/\1 your_new_text_here/'  Input_file
```

Using `sed` mechanism of storing matched regex values into tempraory buffer. Taking everything into 1st buffer till `=` and then keeping rest of the line's value without storing onto buffer. Finally substituting whole line with 1st value and new value

Comment: Since I have multiple lines with `expr1 = expr2` in the text file, that command changes all right hand sides in all lines.

Comment: @mahmood, please check now, it will look for lines which have `Date expire` only and then do substitution to it.

Comment: @mahmood, For any shell variables using in `sed` try something like `sed "/Date expire/s/\(.*= \).*/\1 ${MYDATE}/"  Input_file`.